# Flutter iOS: taps on the status bar can't scroll to top

Tags: flutter

CustomScrollView used in home page layout
If you want to pull up and load more, you must define a ScrollController and pass it to CustomScrollView.

My code

```
ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels >=
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        _loadMoreData();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }
new CustomScrollView(
  controller: _scrollController,
  slivers: <Widget>[....],
)
```

However, if this is done, when there is a lot of data loaded, tap the status bar at the top will not scroll to the top!
If you remove the controller in CustomScrollView, or change to PrimaryScrollController.of(context)

```
new CustomScrollView(
  controller: PrimaryScrollController.of(context),
)
```

this is OK!
why ???

Answer (score 2):

Because Flutter engine tries to imitate the OS behaviour as closely as possible. This tap gesture is known as ["return-to-top"](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/platform-adaptations#return-to-top) on iOS and doesn't exist on Android at all. Furthermore, to stay as close to the iOS app behaviour as possible, this gesture only triggers the scrolling animation for `PrimaryScrollController` classes.

As a reference, in iOS native app development the scroll-to-top gesture has no effect if there is more than one scroll view on-screen that has scrollsToTop set to true ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619421-scrollstotop)).